# az cli create webapp fails with ResourceNotFound error

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, az

This command fails

```
az webapp create --resource-group my-rg -n my-app --plan my-plan
```

with error

> ResourceNotFound - The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/my-app'
> under resource group 'my-rg' was not found.

To me this doesn't make sense. The very purpose of this command is to create the webapp, so obviously it should not expect it to exist before executing the command. Did I miss somthing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think is happening - the App Service name is already taken and it spits out this silly error, try changing the name to something unique and it will work.

ps. figured it out with a `--debug` added to the command

Comment: i didn't know about this `--debug` command, very useful indeed. Unfortunately it gives me the same error. One thing I noticed is that in the resource explorer if I browse to the resource group, there is no Microsoft.Weg/sites node. Should this be created before I can create a webapp ?  If so, how do I do it  ?

Comment: hum.... sorry you are right, I've changed the name of the webapp and now it works indeed. But the error message was the same, even with --debug. Problem solved, thanks

Comment: right, but you need to look at the whole debug output, not just the error message ;) in there it would say something like: `name already taken` and then what would happen - it would attempt to update it (thinking it exists)

Comment: indeed, found the message saying the name already exists :) thanks, that was very useful info.